# Insert current page, id, date into mySQL table

Tags: php, mysql, joomla

In my Joomla 2.5.14 I'm trying to insert the current page_id, user_id and date into a mySQL table (called xmb9d_hist).

This is the code I'm using:

```
<?php
/* Define $jinput */
$jinput = JFactory::getApplication()->input;

/* Get the current page id */
$page= $jinput->get('id');

/* Get the current user id */
$user =JFactory::getUser();
$usr_id = $user->get('id');

/* Get the current date */
$date =JFactory::getDate();

/* Open a connection */

$link=mysqli_connect('localhost','peter','abc123');
    if(!$link){
    echo "Não há ligação!";
    exit();
    };

/* Insert current user id, page id and date in to table xmb9d_hist */
mysqli_query($link, "INSERT INTO `portalge_formacao`.`xmb9d_hist` (`user_id`, `page_id`, `date`) VALUES ($usr_id, $page, $date)");

/* Close connection */
mysqli_close($link);

?>
```

The first part of the code is working ok (retrieving the values for the 3 variables. However, the data isn't being inserted in the database and no error is produced.

In MySQL table, user_id and page_id are defined as INT(11) and date as date.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: are you running this code on your actual Joomla site or from an external PHP file?

Comment: from an actual Joomla site

Comment: in that case **do not** use mysqli_connect. You need to be using Joomla coding standards. Have a look at the documentation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see a few issues with your insert query. First off, I believe that `JFactory::getDate()` returns an object, so to get something you can insert into the database you want to do a `toFormat()` on it. Try changing your line from:

```
$date =JFactory::getDate();
```

to this:

```
$date =JFactory::getDate()->toFormat();
```

And since the date isn't an integer, you need to escape the string in your insert, so update that line to this:

```
mysqli_query($link, "INSERT INTO `portalge_formacao`.`xmb9d_hist` (`user_id`, `page_id`, `date`) VALUES ($usr_id, $page, '$date')");
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to stick to Joomla coding standards when using Joomla unless they have not provided a class for whatever you need. Have a read of the documentation before trying something just incase there is information about it.

Try using the following:

```
<?php

$db = JFactory::getDbo();
$date = JFactory::getDate();
$user = JFactory::getUser();

$jinput = JFactory::getApplication()->input;
$page= $jinput->get('id');
$usr_id = $user->get('id');

$query = $db->getQuery(true);   
$columns = array('user_id', 'page_id', 'date');  
$values = array($usr_id, $page, $date);   
$query
    ->insert($db->quoteName('#__hist'))
    ->columns($db->quoteName($columns))
    ->values(implode(',', $values));

$db->setQuery($query);

?>
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Hi, I tried this method too, I guess it will be easier to maintain. But it doesn't update the MySQL table, even when using $date =JFactory::getDate()->toFormat();

Comment: change the table name from `#__portalge_formacao` to `portalge_formacao`

Comment: which table is it? `portalge_formacao` or `xmb9d_hist`?

Comment: The table is xmb9d_hist, the database is portalge_formacao

Comment: ahh sorry, please see my update. assuming this table is in the same database as your Joomla site

Comment: @NunoNogueira if xmb9d is your db prefix you should write the table name #__hist and Joomla! will take care of filling in the prefix.

Comment: @RiccardoZorn only if it is the same table/prefix as the cms table.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the method toSql() , it's for SQL e.g.

```
$date = JFactory::getDate()->toSql();
```

hope this helps